# Alert on Change in /etc/passwd(or any xyz file ) file from Dynatrace

Tags: dynatrace

We are using Dynatrace to monitoring all our infrastructure and we want to monitor some specific files in our servers (I.Ex. /etc/passwd) , but there is no specific monitoring for that. The Dynatrace agent is running inside all our servers.

Does anyone know how to achieve this or has implemented some solution for this?

Thanks.

Comment: did you maybe forget to finish your sentence? I'm confused as to what that last one means

Comment: Done..didnt relised it was trimmed.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding the answer would be a no. Dynatrace supports custom plugin in python and I have written few custom plugins but that are executed per min to send the metrics.

But I don't think so writing a custom plugin for this would be good use case.

For the triggers perspective you can go to the Settings "Anomaly Detection" and check if there is any option but quite sure there is no such option for this configuration.

You can raise an RFE for this -- this is actually a good requirement not from /etc/passwd perspective but from other stuff can be monitored.